# Designing a single look up entity

Tags: design, object-oriented

In almost every application you have this look up entity that provides a dynamic references. This are things like type, category, etc. These entities will always have

```
id, name, desc
```

So at first I designed different entities for each look up. Like

```
education_type, education_level, degree_type....
```

But on a second thought I decided to have on entity for each of these kinds of entities. But when I am done with the design and check the relation this entity will be referenced by almost all entities in the system and I don't believe that is appropriate. So What is your take on this? Can you give me some clear pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this approach, you need to have the following columns:

1. TableID (or a categorization column)
2. Code
3. Description
4. IsActive (to avoid delete)

You will assign tableID=1 for education level, tableID=2 for degree type, etc.

Issues:

0 - Lookup values will not be easily sharable across projects.

1 - You need to build a Primary Key on the composite columns of (TableID and Code) to ensure uniqueness or have the code by sequentially generated column. This would lead to a composite FK which is not very nice. Alternatively, you could add an artificial column to be the PK (auto sequence for ex.).

2 - Each SELECT will have a hard-coded tableID. This could lead to ugly bugs.

3 - Be ware not to loose relationships between entries. For example, eduction level is related to degree type.

4 - Your data model (if you care) will not have meaningful relationships with this look-up table since some of the entries will not apply.

More on that can be found in: [Why is using a common-lookup table to restrict the status of entity wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691580/why-is-using-a-common-lookup-table-to-restrict-the-status-of-entity-wrong/2691633#2691633)

In summary, if you have a small application, this may be tolerable, but if you are developing a large application it is not OK to have several look-ups in 1 big look-up table, at least conceptually.

Comment: That is really helpful and the article in the link is worth reading!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an "Attribute Type" "Attribute Value" situation. With this scenario you always know the "Attribute Type" ahead of time because you will be very close to your data. The benefit allows for adding "Attribute Values" when the need arises.

Here is a couple things to keep in mind...

1. Obsolete Attribute Values probably need to stay in the database indefinetely
2. You need to allow for "None" and "Other" conditions
3. A separate "Sort Order" field at the "Attribute Value" level is a nice feature

Answer (score 1):

I keep them separate from the app, stored in the database, one table per look up type.

I would also consider ways to filter them out of your UI, such as an "Enabled" flag (so a lookup item can be switched on or off), or possibly even a live from/to date.

This way changes can be made to your data without having to redeploy the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

I find that whenever I have many ways of accessing entities, I tend to create a general query method taking generic parameters and using them to access data.  That method stays hidden, and other public methods access it properly according to what you pass it.

In other words, to search for an entity by id, I'd make a method `getById(id)` which then simply calls an inner method `get` which takes an array of parameters that I would pass to the query.

If you have to perform cross-relation checks, I would make the database do as much work as I possibly could before handling it in my program.  This is both for reasons of efficiency as well as simplicity in your code.  If you allow yourself to handle relations, you'll find that you'll be rewriting database logic, with all the complication that comes with it and none of the efficiency.

I'm not sure what you mean by entity, but my definition of entity is like the object-equivalent of a database table.  Relations between entities may require a database table (many-to-many), but they shouldn't get their own entity.

Answer (score 0):

It's a but unclear to me what are you actually asking but I would model things like education type and education level simply as enumerations (not as entities you need to load from the database or even instanciate). In many languages you can augment your enumerations with additional identity and description fields.